# Dynamic Image won't display correctly

Tags: html, iis

I have a very basic page that displays a dynamic image. Here is my very simple code:

```
<html>
<body>
<p><img width=1024 height=768 src="../image/someImage.jpg"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The image gets refreshed every minute by another program.  The issue is that occasionally the html page will not display the updated image on anyone's computer, so it isn't a local cache issue.  I am using IIS6.  The only way to get it to display the updated image is by stopping and starting IIS for that site.

My company only uses IE, but I tried looking at it in FireFox as well and it did the same.

Comment: And you can see that the image is updated every minute on the server?

Comment: yes.  It is updated.  It seems to update slow (it's only 121K and takes about 5 secs to update).

Comment: To completely rule out caching, append a question mark and a random number to the end of the image path. Example: <img src=".../images/someImage.jpg?34523452345">

Comment: I should clarify that each page load should have a different number at the end...in PHP: <img src=".../images/someImage.jpg?<?=rand(0,1000000)?>">

Comment: that did the trip @sudopeople.  I think its a server cache issue though... but that did the trick.  Officially answer the quesion and I'll mark it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick fix, append a question mark and a random number to the end of the image path. PHP Example:

```
<img src=".../images/someImage.jpg?<?=rand(1,100000)?>">
```

The real root of the problem could be expiration headers. You may want to configure the headers for images to expire sometime in the past. Google around for expiration headers.

Comment: Good news. Also check out the "Pragma: no-cache" header. Regarding how to implement custom headers for images in IIS, I have no idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable IIS7 cache:

- Start IIS Manager (type IIS into search programs and files in start menu)
- Navigate to desired site in the Connections tree (Default Web Site)
- Open Output Caching
- Edit Feature Settings
- Uncheck Enable cache and Enable kernel cache